# Self contained powerapp forms/database?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Is it possible to create a self contained Power app that uses a database (loosely a database) to help a user fill out a form and submit that form.  That form data then lives in the app until another user reviews its and then submits it to a list in SharePoint?

I haven't been able to find anything on this specific subject and I am a novice to SharePoint. We just recently switched platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way using Power Apps you can save the data locally within the Power Apps.

Here's what you can do:

1. Create a SharePoint list where temporary data will be saved, when first time user saves the data from Power Apps.
2. Create another permanent list where reviewed data will be stored.
3. After another user reviews the data, save the final data in permanent list & delete it from temporary list (or keep it as it is - depending upon your requirements).

Comment: Ah that's what I thought.  I was trying to avoid our servers lag when we retrieve from sharepoint lists for the data.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way to do it as Power Apps does not support saving data locally. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this answer helped you.